# Search column in Excel, find value, select and delete

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Been awhile since I've done some programming and I'm not having much luck with a simple excel vba macro. I have data in a column and i need to select then delete the cells that do not contain a particular value. My data looks like this in a column:

990ppbAu/1,2
990ppbAu/0,5
990ppbAu/0,5
990ppbAu/0,3
9900ppmZr/29,1
9900ppmZn/5,2
9900ppmZn/1
9900ppmZn/0,8
9900ppmZn/0,5
9900ppmCu/2,8

I need to delete the values or strings that do not contain "Au" in them. Here is the start of my code, it's not much and probably wrong...but I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SearchColumn()
    Dim strAu As String
    Dim rngFound, rngDelete As Range
    strAu = "*Au*"

    'Search Column
    With Columns("AF")
    'Find values without "Au" in string in column AF and delete.
        Set rngFound = .Find(strAu, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If rngFound <> strAu
        'Then select the value and delete
        'Else move onto the next cell until end of the document
    End With
End Sub
```

I should note, some cells have nothing in them, while some have a string value as seen above. I need it to go through the entire column until end of document. There are about 115,000 records in the table. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to delete the contents of the cell or the cell itself (so all other values move up a row)?

Comment: Just the contents of the cell. No movement of all other values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited3** to delete cell content only

**edited 2** make it delete single cell

**edited** to "reverse" the previous filtering criteria and keep cells containing "Au"

if your column has header then you can use this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SearchColumnWithHeader()
    Dim strAu As String

    strAu = "Au"
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range("AF1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*" & strAu & "*"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents 
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is very close, I really appreciate your assistance. It appears to be deleting the entire row, I only need to delete the contents of the cell it self so it remains empty. My column does have a header.

Comment: Got it to work! I changed part of the code that said "EntireRow.Delete" to "ClearContents" and it seems to be doing the job. Thanks again!